# How indent this Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, indentation

I have a simple question. How I indent a very long line. Let's use the traditional 80 caracters.
This is a line in my code:

```
    NSString *count = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [sTemp substringFromIndex:[sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="].location + [sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="].length]];
```

One solution was

```
    NSString *count = [[NSString alloc]                                 //line 1
                            initWithString: [sTemp substringFromIndex:
                                [sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="].location + 
                                [sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="].length]];
```

This is not the best sample, but the idea is:

1. Ok, the first line is the assignment and alloc thing.
2. The line 2 indent with a fell more right space. But, if the name of variable or type is very big, I will have the situation above. What I do?

   ```
   NSStringWithVeryBigType *bigNameVariable = [NSStringWithVeryBigType alloc] 
                     initWithString: [sTemp substringFromIndex:
   ```
3. IN second line I create a new NSString. I can be confuse if the line 3 and 4 (in a bad situation, not this) is the main function creation, or is this new one. Have a good rule about it? And if it have a big name too, what to do again...

In other words, in a big assignment line, what rule I have to fallow?

Comment: You should not be subclassing `NSString` unless you know what you're doing.  Given the nature of this question, I'm going to guess that you don't. No offense, but subclassing the core types is a bad idea.

Comment: @Dave: You're right, but I think that part of the question is more general; given any subclass (using `NSStringWithVeryBigName` as an example) with a long name, what to do?

Comment: @Josh generally, I just let Xcode handle the indenting for me.  Xcode 4 wraps text if it's too long, or you can break up a line yourself by inserting a newline; Xcode will indent the remainder of the line to what it thinks is an appropriate position.

Comment: @Dave: Since Xcode is the only IDE for Cocoa, that's a fair point. I do enough Python coding that I have the habit of a least _trying_ to adhere to 80 characters. :) I certainly take advantage of Xcode's auto-indent, though.

Comment: @Dave: Lol, i will not subclass the NSString, was only a example. But, thanks by the advice.

Comment: @Rodrigo: good. down that path lies madness.... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
NSString *count = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: 
    [sTemp substringFromIndex:
         [sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="].location 
       + [sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="].length]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to squeeze it all into one line. Whenever you have weird nested calls like this, make one or more intermediate variables for readability:

```
NSRange rng = [sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="];
NSUInteger indexAfterCount = rng.location + rng.length;
NSString * countSubString = [sTemp substringFromIndex:indexAfterCount];

NSStringSubclassWithReallyLongName * countString;
countString = [[NSStringSubclassWithReallyLongName alloc] initWithString:countSubString];
```

Comment: hum, ok, can be a good idea. Maybe I have the problem to put "all in one line code", I will try more this.

Answer (score 3):

`[sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="]` is a potentially expensive operation, and you're doing it twice. You should cache the result in a local variable. Since you want to start your substring immediately after the found range, you can use `NSMaxRange()` to conveniently get that value. As well, use `-copy` instead of `-initWithString:` for `NSString`, as it can give you better performance with nearly identical semantics. So:

```
NSRange range = [sTemp rangeOfString:@"count="];
NSString *count = [[sTemp substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] copy];
```